# PHP unpack() analogue functions in Qt4

Tags: php, qt, unpack

How to implement on Qt logic of PHP functions [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)?

Comment: Please explain further more what you are trying to do.

Comment: In PHP I call unpack('N*', "Some String") and it return me an array. I want to take in Qt a QVariantMap the same as an array in PHP after unpacking "Some String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are looking at using QByteArray, and typecasting the output to some format.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#details

Another way to think about this, is you are taking some structure or type, turning it into a long string of ones and zeros, and then on the other end you are switching it back.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need an algorithm for unpack string.